# How do I get the informations from Spotify API and how do I convert the response in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, spotify

I am new to javascript and the APIs, so I'm still learning but I didn't understand the lesson about the APIs so now I am stuck at this part in my project.

Here is what I have to do, I have to create a React app that allows the user to create a playlist and then sends it to Spotify, so I need to take the data of the musics from Spotify and then save the playlist in Spotify.

```
const client_id = "CLIENT_ID"
const redirect_uri = "http://localhost:3000/"

let accessToken;
let url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&response_type=token&state=123"
const Spotify = {
  getAccessToken() {
    if (accessToken) {
      return accessToken;
    } else if (window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/ & /expires_in=([^&]*)/)) {
      accessToken = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
      let expiresIn = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);
      window.setTimeout(() => accessToken = '', expiresIn * 1000);
      window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
    } else {
      window.location(`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${client_id}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirect_uri}`);
    }
  },

  search(term) {
    const response = fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`}
    })
    if (response.ok) {
      const jsonResponse = response.json().then(
        jsonResponse.map((track) => {
          ID: track.id,
          Name: track.name,
          Artist: track.artists[0].name,
          Album: track.album.name,
          URI: track.uri
      }))
    }
  }

  savePlaylist(namePlaylist, [])
};





export default Spotify
```

I am sorry if it is disordered but I am new and haven't understood anything on this lesson, so I don't even know what I expect but tell me what else I have to specify. And one of the errors is at this part:

```
    if (response.ok) {
      const jsonResponse = response.json().then(
        jsonResponse.map((track) => {
          ID: track.id,
          Name: track.name,
          Artist: track.artists[0].name,
          Album: track.album.name,
          URI: track.uri
      }))
    }
```

The errors tells me `unexpected token` talking about the `:` after `"ID", "Name", "Artist", "Album" and "URI"` and also tells me `expected ';'` but there is no logic in my opinion so I really need some help there and I know I may haven't been clear so please ask me anything to make it clearer.

Comment: Try following [this gist](https://gist.github.com/stavros-p/195da405a4a83b2601806ab68e480fa9).

Comment: Why are trying to create another object since you already have one? Just return track, it is a object. Even if you want to create another one, you just return { property1: value1, property2: value2, propertyN: valueN }

Comment: Oh, nice! I googled your code and came up with some variants